# Navigate in DOM with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how is it possible to navigate over all nodes and count the amount of element-nodes?

Is there something necessary like the numerical coding for node types like:
1: for element-nodes
3: for text-nodes
9: for document-nodes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use: `document.getElementsByTagName("*").length`

> Is there something necessary like the numerical coding for node types like: 1: for element-nodes 3: for text-nodes 9: for document-nodes?

No. You *could* write a function which recursively loops over the children of every node (starting at the `document`) and testing the node type of each … but the above approach is simpler.